# Pinning width on UITableView using auto layout does not behave as expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uikit, autolayout

I'm currently busy designing my custom view in a seperate view xib file using auto and is really struggeling to figure this one out.

The problem that I'm facing is that when I set a fixed width constraint (pin width) on the table view say for instance 320 points (in landscape mode), as soon as I test the view by setting the orientation to portrait the contraint is lost and the table gets shrunkken down to 65 points?

What exactly am I doing wrong here or why is that? Or maybe I'm just missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show what constraints exist on the Table View?

Answer (score -3):

I recommend to use the new autolayout-option of iOS 6 only in very special cases. I have tested this option very intensively and find out a lot of bugs, e.g.:

- in the console appear messages indicating apple bugs
- it slows down your UI dramtically
- while layouting constraints suddenly disappear
- the app sometimes crashes with undocumented error messages

Using autolayout is currently very frustrating. Instead of using autolayout I use

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {}
```

to adjust my UI programmatically, which is much easier and faster (at developing and at runtime).

Comment: Telling someone not to use a technology isn't the right answer. Especially when the technology is supported (and recommended) by Apple.

Comment: Agree, I understand that you might also be frustrated with auto layout as I'm sure a lot of us are at times but I still need to know why it does what it does or where I go wrong. Avoiding auto layout all together isn't going to help me much.

Comment: Sometimes it is good to know that some techniques don´t work as expected and described.
I just shared my experience with you. And I mentioned "currently" and I hope that auto-layout becomes working asap.
For me it had been very useful to become aware of others experience. And as I see right know, nobody find another hint or solution.
So, when it was not useful for you to hear about my experience gathered in 5 days of testing, studying, google, stackoverflow... so, thanks for downvoting.